# Re-render when using Socket.IO in React TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sockets, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO to exchange messages in real time.
The client part is written in React TS.
I add each message to an array.
After the client receives the message, all messages are re-rendered in array.
[screenshot in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6msM.png)
How to avoid component re-rendering, but only the last one?

**My client component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IUserProfileViewerProps } from './IUserProfileViewerProps';
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:4000/")

const UserProfileViewer: FC<IUserProfileViewerProps> = ({ userDisplayName, userEmail }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("messageResponse", (data: any) => {
      setMessages([...messages, data])
    });
    console.log('messageResponse', messages);
  }, [socket, messages])

  return (
    <section>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message) => {
          return (
            <li key={message.ts}>
              <div>{message.user}: {message.text}</div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
export default UserProfileViewer;
```

**My server js file:**

```
require("dotenv-extended").load();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const PORT = 4000;
const socketIO = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});
socketIO.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    socketIO.emit("messageResponse", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(": A user disconnected");
    users = users.filter((user) => user.socketID !== socket.id);
    socketIO.emit("newUserResponse", users);
    socket.disconnect();
  });
});
http.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Don't update messages on every socket message.